# Upstream pip dependency is causing pip install to fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I’m trying to resolve a bug within a `pip` package that’s preventing a Dockerfile from getting built and I'd like to better understand what `pip` is doing.

Problem:

When I do a `pip install -r requirements.txt` it proceeds to install the requirements which includes `pathlib` *even though that’s not within requirement.txt*.

This leads me to believe that pip is doing dependency resolution and finding a package that is within requirements.txt, attempting to install it, and then failing because the `pathlib` it is trying to install does not contain `read_text` with the `PosixPath` class (since that was added later after pathlib was added to python in v3.5).

Question:

1. How can I see which package has pathlib as a dependency?
2. Is there are way to prevent pip from installing an upstream dependency?

Comment: 1. After installation completes, run `pip show pathlib | grep -i required-by` and it will list the packages depending on it. 2. `pip install pkgname --no-deps` will skip all transitive dependencies, installing `pkgname` only.